# How to add button switch process to create mode in dynamics crm?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I have an entity with two processes, and I want to display the button switch process in mode create. Normaly, the button doesn't appear still saving the record.
I am working also with ribon workbench to do this, and I didn't find any way to do that with this tool.
Do you pleased have any idea about how to do that?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Processes aren't available until the record has been saved. The reason for this is that Processes are executed on the server, meaning that the record must already exist in the CRM database

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this, is to override the create and add new buttons for the entity, to run js to create an empty shell of the record, then redirect the user to the newly created record, or in the onload of the entity, force a save and refresh, which isn't as clean.

This will result in lots of empty records, so you may want to think about running a batch delete job.